# How do I get rid of <p> tag in manually created block?

Tags: theming, blocks

I'm trying to remove a `<p>` tag from a manually created block. This block only contains an image and nothing else. I have `kpr()` function outputting block variables but am not seeing where, or how the unnecessary `<p>` tag is being generated.

Would the modification occur in `theme_preprocess_block` function? It seems it's not possible to get rid of within the block template file.

Another thing is that my tried was getting turning on `themes info`, clicking the element in hopes of finding some override function, but `themer_info` only shows me block info instead of some function info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in fact because of the text input format. Going to admin/config/content/formats and removing the checkbox for

```
Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)
```

for the input format you're using should do the trick (re-save the block, of course). Also, if you use WYSIWYG editor, it could do some formatting for you and put the image in `<p>` tag.